# How to add a cardview on button click to another activity programatically

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to create a CardView programatically to ANOTHER Activity,

So I have my DrinkActivity and when I click the FAB I want a CardView to appear in my Summary Activity. I have my code but I'm returning null trying to referenace the id from another activity.

```
 // Initialize a new CardView
            CardView card = new CardView(mContext);

            // Set the CardView layoutParams
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            card.setLayoutParams(params);

            // Set CardView corner radius
            card.setRadius(9);

            // Set cardView content padding
            card.setContentPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

            // Set a background color for CardView
            card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC6D6C3"));

            // Set the CardView maximum elevation
            card.setMaxCardElevation(15);

            // Set CardView elevation
            card.setCardElevation(9);

            // Initialize a new TextView to put in CardView
            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setText("CardView\nProgrammatically");
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            // Put the TextView in CardView
            card.addView(tv);

            // Finally, add the CardView in root layout
            mRelativeLayout.addView(card);
        }
```

any help would be appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: why dont you just have two CardViews in both activities? You can not move the same view between two different activities. If you dont want to have duplicate CardViews then use Fragments instead of activities

Comment: Duplicate cardviews won't work for this but a fragment would be fine, how would that differ in creating the cardview in the frag?

Comment: You create a cardView in a fragment the same way you create it in an activity

Comment: I need to create it programmatically when the fab is clicked, I'm trying to create it in a different activity/fragment from where the fab is